# Cannot uncheck checkedItems in setMultiChoiceItems

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using an alert dialog which shows a list of checkable items. I'm filling the list using setMultiChoiceItems with an array of checked items.
Here is the code:

```
boolean[] bChecked={false, true, true};
alertDlgEncrypt.setMultiChoiceItems(m_tabsList, tabChecked, null);
```

It actually works (checked items are checked at the runtime), but I cannot uncheck those checked items (defined in the tabChecked tab). Do I have to uncheck them manually in the listener (null here, for the example) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have a choice click listener, instead of that null :

```
setMultiChoiceItems(m_tabsList, tabChecked, new myListener() )
```

The listener can be empty, it just has to be defined:

```
public class myListener implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener{
    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked ,boolean ceva) {
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking by code you need to use the setItemChecked method like so:

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(filterNames, isPlayerFiltered, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean b){
    isPlayerFiltered[i] = false;
    ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catalin's and Zammbi's answers are correct, there is also another way for this issue. Use this method for listener parameter.

```
    private DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener myListener = new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean b){
    ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
};
```